# I am making an app like tic tac toe and my app crashes after clicking on the button and I think there is some issue with grid layout

Tags: android, androidx, illegalstateexception

### This is Main Activity.

> I think there is some problem with my grid layout as you can see in the stack trace **" Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout"**

My application is in the final stage so please help me complete it.

```
package com.example.connect3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// 0 = yellow, 1 = red

int activePlayer = 0;

boolean gameIsActive = true;

// 2 means unplayed

int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

int[][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};

public void dropIn(View view) {

    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

    int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

    if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameIsActive) {

        gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

        if (activePlayer == 0) {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);

            activePlayer = 1;

        } else {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);

            activePlayer = 0;

        }

        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(360f).setDuration(300);

        for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {

            // logic to store data of counters and stop counters replacement

            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {

                // Someone has won!

                gameIsActive = false;

                String winner = "Red";

                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0) {

                    winner = "Yellow";

                }

                TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);

                winnerMessage.setText(winner + " has won!");

                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);


layout.animate().translationXBy(1000f).translationYBy(1000f).rotation(3600f).setDuration(1000);

                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                boolean gameIsOver = true;

                for (int counterState : gameState) {

                    if (counterState == 2) gameIsOver = false;

                }

                if (gameIsOver) {

                    TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);

                    winnerMessage.setText("It's a draw");

                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);


layout.animate().translationXBy(1000f).translationYBy(1000f).rotation(3600f).setDuration(1000);

                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

public void playAgain(View view) {

    gameIsActive = true;

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

    layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    activePlayer = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++) {

        gameState[i] = 2;

    }

        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {

            ((ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);

        }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

    layout.setTranslationX(-1000f);
    layout.setTranslationY(-1000f);

}
}
```

### This is Full Stack Trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.connect3, PID: 17126
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout
    at com.example.connect3.MainActivity.playAgain(MainActivity.java:133)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

### This is activity_main xml.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="1"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="2"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="3"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="4"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="5"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="6"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="7"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="8"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2" />
    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/wooden"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="playAgain"
            android:text="Play Again" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem in two different ways:

1) move you project to **AndroidX** (highly recommend)
See [Migrate to AndroidX.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

2) In your layout XML use `android.widget.GridLayout` as parent instead of `androidx.widget.GridLayout`
Please note the **x.**

Answer (score 0):

/* public void againP(View view) {
gameactive=true;

```
        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView32)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView33)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView34)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView35)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView24)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView29)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView41)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView42)).setImageResource(0);





        activplay=0;
        ar=new int[9];

    }*/
```